# Filter searchText based on different array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm wondering how I would use Angular's searchText filter search an array specified. Currently, I'm using an ng-repeat and filter:searchText based off of an input.

The issue is that the ng-repeat uses a slice of the full array. So it loops through 10 records of 100. I need it to search the full array instead of the dataset it uses.

```
<input ng-model="searchText" id="ldrSearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="Search" type="text">

<tr id="row%% $index %%" ng-click="toggleDetails($event,true)" ng-repeat-start="user in users | filter:searchText" class="leaderboardrow"> ... </tr>
```

Comment: Angular has no `searchText` filter. `filter:searchText` would mean the `filter` filter with the expression `searchText`. Is it that? Some code would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry about that. So yes, searchText references an input with ng-model "searchText" and it searches the users array for the string passed. However, users is a subset of the main user list because we built in some custom paging. So when we hit our next page button, users will get updated to a slice of the main array. I basically want to filter the main users array when searching.

Comment: Stupid question: If you want to filter the full array, why do you filter the slice then?

Comment: Well, that's part of the question I suppose. I added the filter to the ng-repeat, which filters the sliced data, because that's what the ng-repeat uses. We only want to show 10 records at a time - which is why we slice it. We have a button that will "page" the results - giving a new slice with different offsets to display. Maybe there's a better way of paging?

Comment: If you filter the slice then you may currently have less than 10 entries, but you want to filter the whole data set and always have 10 entries displayed? With the entries and pages changing dynamically? In that case I would use the whole array instead of a slice and add a second (custom) filter to display only the current slice.

Comment: With your comment @zeroflagL, and [this SO post](http://goo.gl/9oFC1X), I was able to complete this. If the internet points matter to you, create an answer and I'll mark it. :) Thanks again.

Comment: You solved it yourself, the points belong to you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the advice of @zeroflagL

> If you filter the slice then you may currently have less than 10
>   entries, but you want to filter the whole data set and always have 10
>   entries displayed? With the entries and pages changing dynamically? In
>   that case I would use the whole array instead of a slice and add a
>   second (custom) filter to display only the current slice.

as well as [this SO post](http://goo.gl/9oFC1X).

The only difference is that with my "slice" i used variables to set the start and end.

```
<tr id="row%% $index %%" ng-click="toggleDetails($event,true)" ng-repeat-start="user in users | filter:searchText | page:start:end"> .. </td>

app.filter('page',function()
    {
        return function(arr,start,end)
        {
            return (arr || []).slice(start, end);
        };
    });
```